# Virtualbox not recognizing GRUB

Tags: virtualbox, dd, grub2, vdi

I ripped a Linux Mint partition into a file using the dd command:

```
sudo dd if=PART_PATH of=OUTPUT_PATH/ubuntu.bin
```

Then I converted it into a *.vdi

```
VBoxManage convertdd PATH_TO_ubuntu.bin ubuntu.vdi --format VDI
```

But when I try to boot into the vdi from Virtualbox I get an error

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found? System halted.
```

Even though I chose the *.vdi file as the hard drive.

So I tried booting into a live CD and the virtual hard drive shows up as /dev/sda, I was able to mount it and browse system files. So the *.vdi file is working but I can't boot.

I tried to `chroot` into the system in the VDI via the live system and ran the command to rebild GRUB but it didn't do anything. I also tried `boot-repair`.

**How do I make VirtualBox boot into the ripped *.vdi instead of it just being read like a storage hard drive?**

Comment: To be bootable, a disk and therefore also a VDI file needs a partition table. It also needs Grub itself (MBR format: Grub resides in a gap between partition table and first partition; UEFI: Grub resides in an EFI partition), and the Grub config file, which is often in a separate partition mounted under /boot. Since you only copied a single partition to the VDI file, I guess that all of the above is missing in the VDI file.

Comment: I found instructions almost identical to your steps at https://askubuntu.com/a/34879/1039187, but at least two people report the same problem as you. Try copying the entire disk instead of just the partition.

Comment: Maybe the easiest thing to do is to install the same distro of Linux from scratch using the Virtual Box wizard, then attach the VDI, move it to a partition alongside the working system then finally from within the working install chroot into the partition and rebuild GRUB.